# Unable to use SocketIOClientDotNet with external server

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm having trouble getting SocketIoClientDotNet to connect with an external server. Here's a basic example using the websocket.org echo server. I've tried my own ws server as well. I can't ever get a connect event to occur. I tried this with a vanilla console C# program. Tried messing around with options as well, but that had no effect.

```cs
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var socket = IO.Socket("ws://echo.websocket.org");            
            Test(socket).Wait();

        }

        public static Task<bool> Test(Socket s)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            s.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            });
            s.Connect();
            return tcs.Task;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where you able to resolve this issue, I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope. I ended up writing my own library. There were really no good solutions out there for .NET